# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters in CI for different language url

Tags: php, codeigniter, urldecode

I am using code igniter and in my website I use multiple language for single url to show the content. Work good on everything but while translating one of the url, it broke.

My URL is

```
https://mydomain/it/pi%C3%B9-raccomandazioni
```

But somehow it got converted to

```
https://mydomain/it/più-raccomm&azioni
```

whereas this should be

```
https://mydomain/it/più-raccomandazioni
```

the letter "and" in raccomandazioni is getting converted into '&'.

I have tried to use this fix and it did remove the error but it still replace the character which actually didn't show the page.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-';
```

Comment: *but while translating one of the url*: how do you do that?

Comment: we have set of words for which we have manual translation. So whenever these words show up, we translate it

Comment: that's not what I meant, how to you get the url string, which function (urlencode, etc.) do you use, how is that stored in the database, what is the db collation?